# Tracking down a copy of "Mixed categories, Ext-duality and representations (results and conjectures)"

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

I am trying to find a copy, ideally digital, of the following preprint:

Title: Mixed categories, Ext-duality and representations
(results and conjectures)

Authors: A. Beilinson and V. Ginzburg

Year: 1986

Motivation: This preprint stimulated a lot of amazing work, including the birth of Soergel bimodules and the seminal paper "Koszul duality patterns in representation theory" by Beilinson-Ginzburg-Soergel ten years later. So, I am very curious to learn what their viewpoint and expectations were as early as '86.

Thank you for taking a look at this, and I appreciate any help you can provide!